# Отношение, кортеж, атрибут

Tags: sql

В SQL Отношение - таблица, кортеж - строка (запись), атрибут это информация/данные в "ячейках" таблицы. А вот если ячейка но там значение null это считается за атрибут?(что это данные/информация).

Comment: null - это отсутствие информации и соответственно отсутствие значения атрибута

Comment: @Viktorov атрибут это получается ячейка, но сама информация/данные это значения?

Comment: я не понимаю, что вы спрашиваете. попробуйте переформулировать вопрос

Comment: @Mike Mclaren вы маленько запутались. Атрибут - это, если по простому, наименование столбца, то что обозначает столбец . А содержимое "ячейки" - это значение. Если в ячейке стоит null, то значение атрибута неизвестно.